# Setting pandas set_option globally for particular venv

Tags: python, pandas

- I find myself setting the pd.set_option in multiple files and forgetting about them
- Is there any performance issues with setting these values so large, I tend to do this in DEV?
- Is there a way to set an .env variable or pandas config globally so that all modules/scripts that leverage pandas inherit these options? Then I can revert back to a smaller value in PROD

  `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000, 'display.width', 1000, 'display.max_columns', 1000)`

Comment: If you are are using ipython then you can create a startup script.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment

Comment: No currently, using a remote python36 on aws ec2. Is there a similar startup script concept for regular python?  I wondering if I should create a custom module to import pandas and ps.set_option, and then import that module elsewhere in the code base....but seems like a hack to me